# How to replicate these locale settings in the console?

Tags: debian, locale

I'm not an UI-person, but a terminal person. I prefer to do my work in terminals. However, this time when I upgraded a debian package (I forgot which) the whole locale system went down the drain.

I do not want one single system wide locale. I want English for all applications, so en_GB is the first choice. However, en_GB has broken time format (mm/dd/yy) so en_DK fixes this (yy-mm-dd). However, using this as a system wide locale makes my swedish keyboard go bork, because `ls` screws up the filenames containing Swedish characters (åäöÅÄÖ).

This screenshot - from whatever the dinosaur bloat UI in Debian is - shows what I want to achieve:

[image]

But trying to replicate this in terminal, Debian yells at me because locale is broken.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_GB:en",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_CTYPE = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "custom.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
```

How do I fix this mess according to my preference?

Comment: en_GB uses dd/mm/yyyy, at least it does on my Debian 10 system...

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy are both wrong in my book, that's why I want yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: I understand, I’m not questioning your wish for a different date format, just the statement that en_GB’s date format is mm/dd/yy.

Comment: What if you prefix your "sudo dpkg-... " with LC_ALL=C? Or better in 2 lines : (1) export LC_ALL=C (2) sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

Comment: Also is it en_DK or en_DK.utf8 you are having screw up non ASCII chars?

Answer (score 0):

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

I think. File /etc/default/locales.

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried to no avail.

Comment: Did you reboot/login again?